# Move img to a different bootstrap col on breakpoint

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, function

Using Bootstrap 4, I have a `<container>` that has two columns.

On screen sizes that fall within the [boostrap 4 breakpoints](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/)  **md-xl**, these are arranged in two equally sized columns: `col-md-6`, and stack into a single column on **sm-xs** screens: `col-xs-12`.

**I want to move the blue `img` above the red `img` on *md* screens** (so from one `col` to another - see diagram below). I've had a play around with some javascript and [Node.insertBefore()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore), but if possible would prefer to do this using Bootsrap4 CSS.

[image]

Below is a first attempt that I made with some remedial javascript - Can someone point me in the right direction?

```js
function movelogo() {
    var logo = document.getElementById('logo');
    logo.insertBefore(logo, 'next_col');
}


window.addEventListener('resize', movelogo);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 viewport-fit=cover">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html"/>
    <title>Title</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Font Awesome CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css"
          integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">

</head>
<body>

<div id="about" class="container">
    <h1 class="text-center display-3 mb-4">About</h1>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">

            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/0000FF/808080?text=Logo" class="img-fluid mb-5 mx-auto d-block"
                 id="logo" alt="Logo">

            <p>Metuentes igitur idem latrones Lycaoniam magna parte campestrem cum se inpares nostris fore congressione
                stataria documentis frequentibus scirent, tramitibus deviis petivere Pamphyliam diu quidem intactam sed
                timore populationum et caedium, milite per omnia diffuso propinqua, magnis undique praesidiis
                conmunitam.</p>

            <p> Quid enim tam absurdum quam delectari multis inanimis rebus, ut honore, ut gloria, ut aedificio, ut
                vestitu cultuque corporis, animante virtute praedito, eo qui vel amare vel, ut ita dicam, redamare
                possit, non admodum delectari? Nihil est enim remuneratione benevolentiae, nihil vicissitudine studiorum
                officiorumque iucundius.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" id="next_col">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x600/FF0000/FFFFFF?text=Image" alt="Main image"
                 class="mx-auto d-block img-fluid">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you using JS to move the logo? Are you just testing how insertNode works? You can simply use responsive Bootstrap CSS classes.

Comment: Please explain why this has a bounty and the existing answer isn't adequate.

Comment: @Zim - exactly as I said in my comment. When I resize the viewport I don't see the reordering that I am after. I'll expand my question a little...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way of doing it in simple JS using [Media Queries with JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_media_queries.asp) without changing your HTML, just by adding an `id="current_col"` to your logo div.

(I put an `sm-6` in the snipper bellow for you to see the result directly in here)

```js
function resize(x) {
  if (x.matches) { // If media query matches
    document.getElementById('next_col').prepend(
      document.getElementById('logo')
    );
  } else {
    if ($("#next_col").children("#logo").length > 0) {
      document.getElementById('current_col').prepend(
        document.getElementById('logo')
      );
    }
  }
}

var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 960px)")
resize(x) // Call listener function at run time
x.addListener(resize) // Attach listener function on state changes
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 viewport-fit=cover">
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
  <title>Title</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Font Awesome CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Custom CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">

</head>

<body>

  <div id="about" class="container">
    <h1 class="text-center display-3 mb-4">About</h1>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6" id="current_col">

        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/0000FF/808080?text=Logo" class="img-fluid mb-5 mx-auto d-block" id="logo" alt="Logo">

        <p>Metuentes igitur idem latrones Lycaoniam magna parte campestrem cum se inpares nostris fore congressione stataria documentis frequentibus scirent, tramitibus deviis petivere Pamphyliam diu quidem intactam sed timore populationum et caedium, milite
          per omnia diffuso propinqua, magnis undique praesidiis conmunitam.
        </p>

        <p> Quid enim tam absurdum quam delectari multis inanimis rebus, ut honore, ut gloria, ut aedificio, ut vestitu cultuque corporis, animante virtute praedito, eo qui vel amare vel, ut ita dicam, redamare possit, non admodum delectari? Nihil est enim
          remuneratione benevolentiae, nihil vicissitudine studiorum officiorumque iucundius.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6" id="next_col">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x600/FF0000/FFFFFF?text=Image" alt="Main image" class="mx-auto d-block img-fluid">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

You can test it here : 
https://jsfiddle.net/748sormv/

Comment: This looks very nice, and it works exactly as I want - thanks! Let me play around with it a bit...

Comment: @fugu you're welcome - I tried to keep your format as still as possible and use a simple JS logic. Feel free to ask me any questions you'd like. `window.matchMedia` is a powerful way to manipulate media queries using javascript.

Comment: I've just tested it and it works well on Chrome and Firefox, but not on Safari. I've tried `window.matchMedia("screen and (max-width: 960px)"` as suggested here http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries4.shtml, but that doesn't fix the problem

Comment: @fugu you can see a compatibility list [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia), you need it to work on safari below version 5 and on opera? As all newest browsers and updated browsers work with no problem.

Comment: I'm on safari 12 and it doesn't work. I'll have another look at my script and see if I can work out why it's not working

Comment: @fugu do keep me updated as I unfortunately have no access to a safari v12. I'm sure you know but you can use [jsfiddle as a page](https://jsfiddle.net/748sormv/show) for easier testing on browsers.

Comment: Not sure why it wasn't working before but it works on Safari now. Thanks this is exactly what I was trying to do!

Comment: @fugu happy to help, see you around! :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues...

- `next_col` is a string not a Node.
- using `logo.insertBefore(logo, 'next_col');` is trying to insert the `logo` into *itself* before `next_col` which OFC doesn't exist inside logo.

> "The below code attempts to move the logo on any screen size (and I
>   will worry about detecting the screen size later)."

That means *every* time the window resize event fires it will attempt the insertBefore which will most likely crash the browser. You need some test condition, and to fix the other issues....

```
function movelogo() {
    var logo = document.getElementById('logo');
    var next_col = document.getElementById('next_col');
    if (logo.parentNode !== next_col) {
        next_col.insertBefore(logo, next_col.childNodes[0]);
    }
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/G8zYKzmnZf

---

But, there's really no reason to use JS since Bootstrap is responsive and can be used to change the layout on xs and sm screen widths: https://www.codeply.com/go/rh6PfIucow

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't know about the Bootstrap approach of ordering cols, so glad to know that I don't need js. However, can you explain what's going on in your snippet? It doesn't seem to reorder anything...

Comment: It does reorder the image and logo...OFC you have to resize the viewport

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution; you will have to view it full size and then resize the window to under 480px to see the result. 
I included a media query to resolve your question. I also created two new containing divs in your HTML, `bluecol` and `redcol`.

The `bluecol` div surrounds the blue image and it's text. The `float:left` is in the media query for the text div to align it to the left on resize. Initially I put the text div after the image in the code, but then the text displays first on the larger screen. I removed some of the inline bootstrap css and added some newly-created (short) custom classes to achieve the end result.

Hope this is of help.

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

#abouttxt {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 10pt;
  line-height:1.4em;
  margin-top:12px;
  
}

#logo {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 20%;
}

#abouttxt,
#logo {
  display: inline-block;
}


.red {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 10%;
}

#bluecol,
#redcol {
  display: block;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:480px) {
  #abouttxt {
    max-width: 50%;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 10pt;
    float: left;
  }
  #logo {
    max-width: 40%;
    margin: 5px 10px;
  }
  #abouttxt,
  #logo {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  .red {
    width: 40%;
    margin-left: 52%;
  }
  #bluecol,
  #redcol {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 viewport-fit=cover">
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
  <title>Title</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Font Awesome CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Custom CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">

</head>

<body>

  <div id="about" class="container">
    <h1 class="text-center display-3 mb-4">About</h1>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">

      <div id="bluecol" class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">

        <img id="logo" alt="Logo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/0000FF/808080?text=Logo" />
        <section id="abouttxt">
          <p class="btext">Metuentes igitur idem latrones Lycaoniam magna parte campestrem cum se inpares nostris fore congressione stataria documentis frequentibus scirent, tramitibus deviis petivere Pamphyliam diu quidem intactam sed timore populationum et caedium,
            milite per omnia diffuso propinqua, magnis undique praesidiis conmunitam.
          </p>

          <p class="btext"> Quid enim tam absurdum quam delectari multis inanimis rebus, ut honore, ut gloria, ut aedificio, ut vestitu cultuque corporis, animante virtute praedito, eo qui vel amare vel, ut ita dicam, redamare possit, non admodum delectari? Nihil est enim
            remuneratione benevolentiae, nihil vicissitudine studiorum officiorumque iucundius.</p>
        </section>


      </div>

      <div id="redcol" class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <img class="red" class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x600/FF0000/FFFFFF?text=Image" alt="Main image">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think that he wants a way to do it without changing the HTML

Comment: Thanks, this is nice. @IslamElshobokshy, I'm not so bothered about changing the HTML if there's a better way of writing what I have already - always open to suggestions (particularly as I'm pretty new to html/css!)